# Angular + d3: Animation of svg creates horrible CD thrashing

Tags: angular, d3.js, zonejs

So, I have a component that contains some d3. It's not extremely complicated. But the SVG needs to be in constant transition. In order for that to happen. Once the function that does the transition runs, it then sets a timeout to call itself again in a few seconds.

When this code is running, the fan on my computer immediately turns on and the CPU jumps to 40% +/-. If I simply build the svg and then don't run the animation in asyn loop, then the CPU is only a few percent. Just as I would expect. When I pause the JS execution in DevTools, the call stack points to a CD cycle.

My question is: How do I get a d3 animation to not force Angular's change detection to run so crazy?

Here is the code that is running. It is inside one of my classes:

```
const animate = () => {
    // this points to a piece of the SVG in my template
    gradient
        .transition()
        .duration(6001)
        .ease(d3.easeSin)
        .attr('r', 0.65)
        .transition()
        .duration(6001)
        .ease(d3.easeSin)
        .attr('r', 0.35);

    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(animate);
        }, 12003);
    });
};

this.zone.runOutsideAngular(animate);
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

- As you can see, I tried wrapping it with the `runOutsideAngular` calls. Didn't help.

  - I changed the ChangeDetectionStrategy of my component to be OnPush. Didn't help.
  - I added the import of `d3` before the import of `zone.js`, hoping that all of the `d3` functions would init before the zones are setup and running. Didn't help.

I just want this animation to run outside of Angular. Here is an example of the component. If you open it, notice that the CPU usage on that tab in your browser will spike to 30%, 40%, 50%? https://plnkr.co/edit/VQAuQzA2JzKNoArmgbfn?p=preview

Comment: I can easily remove this feature from my app. But... I love the way that this pulsing animation looks, and I want to keep it there. So... any help... I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Try to detach the cdr from your component.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to do that. If you look at the plunker, you can see what I did to attempt what you are saying. The problem still seems to be happening.

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS + Keyframe animation to achieve this pulse effect? Do you need D3 for something else later?

Comment: Not yet. I could get rid of it. I will try that.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Even running it concurrently on Chrome, FF and Edge adds at most 10% to the overall CPU load. Any single browser instance adds an average load of somewhat around 2%. What device / browser setup are you running this on?

Comment: @altocumulus I think that it is a CPU vs GPU thing. If you look at your GPU, it should be going high. I think that on my older MBP, it using the CPU to process the graphics stuff, but on nicer laptops, they are using their GPU.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

1. remove
2. before load zone.js, add this flag.
   __Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;

here is the updated sample.

```
__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ft1AdgMh9cGR5rfSxbkk?p=preview